# How to open MySQL database from docker container in my local HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, docker, centos, heidisql

I ran centos/mysql-57-centos7 container with

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root centos/mysql-57-centos7
```

and it works well

```
ae0b9060f99c        centos/mysql-57-centos7   "container-entrypoin…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp            angry_blackwell
```

but I don`t know how to connect it with my HeidiSQL, i saw the container ip with

```
docker inspect -f <ContainerID>  //172.17.0.2
```

and I tried to open with the following login:

user: root, pass: root, hostname/ip: 172.17.0.2 port: 3306 but I get: **Can`t connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2 (10060)'**

Comment: As you can see at the [centos/mysql-57-centos7](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/mysql-57-centos7/) docker hub page, the username/password can be passed as environment variables when you run the container, for example: `docker run -d --name mysql_database -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -p 3306:3306 ...`

Comment: Yes, I changed them with root and I ran it with my settings. In my opinion, I cant connect because centos is not configured to provide services for different ips/machines but I don`t know how to make it to be available for my pc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, MySQL only allow root login on localhost.
My advice is to create a new user for you remote access : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html

Comment: Yeahhh ! Thanks @Philoupe , that was the correct solution, I changed them and i logged in immediately ! Honestly, i had other problems with this distribution and I changed it with linuxserver/mysql image. I logged in with hostname: localhost, port:3306 and my custom user & pass (different than root) ! :)

Comment: FYI I changed the linux because of many problems with the user permissions, here I just logged in the linux with 'mysql -u root -p' with the root password and i can control everything ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward a port
"docker run -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root centos/mysql-57-centos7"
and then connect to localhost:3306.

Comment: This is not fully correct (at least for the linux case). You don't have to `publish` a port if we are talking about the same host. On linux, the default bridge network assigns `172.17.0.1` to your host and as a result any container with IP `172.17.0.x` is directly accessible. Maybe the OP should add what platform is being used...

Comment: The 172.17.0.0/16 addresses (a) are hard to find and (b) don't work from a different host.  You don't need them and should probably never use them.  From the same host, use `localhost` (as this answer suggests); from other containers, use inter-container DNS; from other hosts, use the host's DNS name or IP address.

Comment: Yes, David Maze, thats true ! Thanks, I logged in with localhost ! :)